# Customizing IndicatingAjaxLink in wicket

Tags: java, wicket

in my current project i've faced a problem of customizing IndicatingAjaxLink in wicket, is there any solution to change standart gif image to my own? 
For example we have following listeneer

```
   add(new IndicatingAjaxLink("closeReceivedBillspanel") {
            public void onClick(AjaxRequestTarget art) {
                  // some timeconsuming calculations
           }
   });
```

as user clicks this link, the gif with loading appears, and i want to change this gif, is there any solution for this problem?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Have your page implements the IAjaxIndicatorAware interface

```
public class BasePage extends WebPage implements IAjaxIndicatorAware {   

 public BasePage(final PageParameters parameters) {
    // Home link
    AjaxLink<Page> homeLink = new AjaxLink<Page>("homeLink") {
      private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

      @Override
      public void onClick(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
        setResponsePage(HomePage.class);
      }
    };
    add(homeLink);
  }

  @Override
  public String getAjaxIndicatorMarkupId() {
    return "indicator";
  }
```

This way, you can set, in the html, any image you want to display when the loading appears by changing the image in the "img" tag

```
<div id="indicator" style="display: none;">
 <div class="indicator-content">
  Please wait... <wicket:link><img src="images/loading.gif" width="16" height="16" alt="loading" /></wicket:link>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Create yoru own custom class like, (copy whats inside IndicatingAjaxLink and update)

```
   public class MyIndicatingAjaxLink<T> extends AjaxLink<T> implements IAjaxIndicatorAware {
         private final MyAjaxIndicatorAppender indicatorAppender = new MyAjaxIndicatorAppender();    
    .
    //rest of the code is same as IndicatingAjaxLink class
    .
    }
```

Also you need a custom AjaxIndicatorAppender within your customIndicatingAjaxLink and you need to override below method of indicatorAppender to return path of your custom image

```
protected CharSequence getIndicatorUrl()
```